# Symmetries and equations of superspheres and other superspaces

Tags: symmetry, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra, superspace-formalism

What are the symmetries and the most studied/most standard examples of superspaces? I include exceptional superalgebras and infinite-dimensional spaces.
Bonus: Do quantum groups apply in the above classification somehow or are they apart?

Comment: By “supersphere” I don’t think you mean [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Supersphere.html). What *do* you mean by supersphere?

Comment: *the most important examples* This makes your question an off-topic opinion-based one.

Comment: @Ghoster that is not a "supersphere" in superspace...

Comment: Aren’t the squares of fermionic coordinates in superspace zero? If so, how can you have a supersphere in superspace?